# Для чего необходимо свойство ValueMember компонента LookUpEdit

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

Зачем нам надо `ValueMember` в `LookUpEdit`? Как это вообще может помочь?

Comment: Можно подробностей?

Comment: Ну и, чтобы не быть обвиненным в нежелании помочь, гляньте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718512/how-to-set-devexpress-lookupedit-selected-text-in-gridvidew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компонент `LookUpEdit` позволяет отделить редактируемое значение от отображаемого текста. Например, редактировать числовое поле, а пользователю показывать осмысленный текст.

Для чего это нужно. Самый распространенный вариант применения - редактирование внешнего ключа, который ссылается на запись в другой таблице.

Возьмем, к примеру, две связанные таблицы: `Author` и `Book`. В последней имеется поле `AuthorID`, которое пользователь может редактировать. При этом, мы не хотим показывать пользователю идентификаторы строк. Пользователю удобнее видеть значение поля `FullName`, которое хранится в таблице `Author`.

Для этой цели и служит редактор `LookUpEdit`. Его можно заполнить строками из таблицы `Author`, и указать что для присваивания в `AuthorID` нужно брать значение из поля `ID`, а для отображения пользователю нужно брать значение из свойства `FullName`. Для этого и нужны свойства `DisplayMember` и `ValueMember`.